# hiding a field using Openerp report designer

Tags: report, odoo, designer

I am using OpenERP report designer to alter the sales order report a bit.

Background:

I am trying to remove the internal reference of a product that appears in my invoices, sales orders and quotations....

Actions done:
I have created a new field through the delevoper mode and named it x_showintref which is a boolean ('x_showintref': fields.boolean('Show Internal Reference'))...

What to do:

I am trying to edit the sales - quotation report so that when the x_showintref is ticked, it will display the internal reference else it will not display the Internal Reference of the product.

Other Ideas:
Is there a way one can put this in a python script as well??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your report. This will work.

```
[[ o.x_showintref==True and line.product_id.default_code or line.name ]]
```

Comment: can i put this anywhere in the report or does it have to be under the description part of the table??

Comment: No, In simply replace with this line `<para style="terp_default_9">[[ format(line.name) ]] </para>` for checking purpose.

Comment: It works partially in the sense that I still want the description to show.

Comment: when x_showintref is ticked, it shows the internal reference only and when it is not ticked, it shows nothing... I want it show the product name no matter what but just leave out the internal reference when x_showintref isnt ticked...

Comment: means if field is ticked we need to show internal reference and if not ticked than we need to display description right ? according that, updated my answer.

Comment: okay so if marked display "[LW101] Large White Shirts" but if not marked show "Large White Shirts"

Comment: so if x_showintref is ticked then it displays "[LW101] Large White T-Shirts" and if it is not ticked then display "Large White T-Shirts"

Comment: above condition will be based on `x_showintref.` you can do what ever you want if that field is true. For example `[[ o.x_showintref==True and place true value or place false value ]]` true value = [LW101] Large White Shirts and false value = Large White Shirts. Yes we need to write code for that and their is no setting for this. hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks alot.  You really gave me some insight to this.... I really appreciate your assistance