# How to hide fields in OpenERP report using OpenOffice?

Tags: report, field, odoo, openoffice-writer

I'm new to OpenOffice and I don't know how to do it.
I have two fields one is text field and the other one is boolean (namely text_field and boolean_field), I just wanted to disable and enable the visibility of the text field and its column description from the report based on the boolean field value.How can i do this?

Comment: for more reference visit this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762142/hiding-a-field-using-openerp-report-designer/25762863#25762863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your report. This will work.

```
[[ o.boolean_field==True and o.text_field or removeParentNode('para') ]]
```